# How to get words "Month", "Day" and "Year" in different languages from .net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I have three dropdown lists for date of birth in my multilingual application.
I am able to get the month names in different languages and put them into dropdown list.

However I would like to add actual words "Month", "Day" and "Year" as a first item in the dropdowns. Of course, I could easily add string "Month" as first item, but I need this to be multilingual. I am trying to avoid long case statements and tons of strings (application supports 24 languages).

Is there a way to do this in .net? I am not asking for how to output months names, but how to output actual words "Month", "Day", and "Year" in different languages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way as you would do it for any other word: localize your application. A good default approach to doing this (much better than case statements) is [using resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228208.aspx). Obviously, you will not be able to avoid the tons of strings as there is no localization fairy.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Resource Strings](http://development.meritsolutions.com/matters/localization-and-globalization-in-c-localization/) to localize, you can translate any text to any language in this way. It will always be a lot of work with 24 languages.